# React.js : Rendering the same component differently based on the id passed

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am using react, I have a component called NaturalPerson and I am using this component in my navigation component . I want to render the same component(NaturalPerson) in a different way based on the id passed. Is there a way to do this?

NaturalPerson :

```
module.exports = React.createClass({

    getInitialState :function() {
    return{
             readOnly : true

          };
          },

          submit : function(){
            this.setState({readOnly : false});
          },
          save : function(){
            return '/';
          },

      render: function render() {

        return (<div id="container_suspects">
         <button type="button" onClick={this.submit} >Edit Details</button>
        <div id="suspects_personal_details"><PD hidden="hidden"  readOnly={this.state.readOnly}/><br/><br/>
        <PNS hidden="hidden" readOnly={this.state.readOnly}/><br/><br/>
        <Email readOnly={this.state.readOnly} /><br/><br/></div>
        <div id="suspects_address"><A  readOnly={this.state.readOnly}/><br/><br/></div>
       </div>

        );
      }
});
```

nav.jsx :

```
module.exports = React.createClass({

  displayName: 'nav',

  render: function render() {   
    var activeClass = 'left-nav-selected';

    return (
      <section className='left-nav' id='left-nav'>
        <div className='left-nav-title'>{this.props.name}</div>
        <nav className='left-nav-links'>
          <ul>
            <li className='left-nav-link' id='nav-section1'>
              <Link to={this.props.section1} params={{naturalPersonId: 1}} className={this.props.navSelection==='nav-section1'?activeClass:''} 
                    activeClassName={activeClass}>{this.props.nav1}</Link>
            </li>
            <li className='left-nav-link' id='nav-section2'>
              <Link to={this.props.section2} params={{naturalPersonId: 2}} className={this.props.navSelection==='nav-section2'?activeClass:''} 
                    activeClassName={activeClass}>{this.props.nav2}</Link>
            </li>
            <li className='left-nav-link' id='nav-section3'>
              <Link to={this.props.section3} params={{naturalPersonId: 3}} className={this.props.navSelection==='nav-section3'?activeClass:''} 
                    activeClassName={activeClass}>{this.props.nav3}</Link>
            </li>   
            <li className='left-nav-link' id='nav-section4'>
              <Link to={this.props.section4} params={{naturalPersonId: 4}} className={this.props.navSelection==='nav-section4'?activeClass:''} 
                    activeClassName={activeClass}>{this.props.nav4}</Link>
            </li>     
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </section>
    );
  }
});
```

routes.jsx :

```
<Route name='NaturalPerson' path='NaturalPerson/:naturalPersonId' handler={NaturalPerson}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to get the `naturalPersonId` from your Route and add conditionals depending on the input you're getting. Here's one way of doing that:

```
render: function render() {
  let id = this.props.routeParams.naturalPersonId;
  return (
    //JSX goes here...
  );
}
```

alternatively, you could do a conditional inside your render and call different functions accordingly:

```
render: function render() {
  let id = this.props.routeParams.naturalPersonId;
  if(id == 1) {
    return this.customRenderOne();
  } else {
    return this.customRenderTwo();
  }
}
```

Comment: It says "Cannot read property 'naturalPersonId' of undefined" . How can I access naturalPersonId?

Comment: @medha You are using `react-router` correct? Can you provide the output for `console.log(this.props)`?

Comment: @medha, for the record, my code would go in your `NaturalPerson` class, not the other one.

Comment: Object {params: Object, query: Object} . This is the output of console.log(this.props)

Comment: Are you sure you have implemented `react-router` properly? Could you paste your whole project on [pastebin](http://http://pastebin.com) or similar?